# C# .Net Converted Code Performance Issue

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, matlab

I am processing large files and using some algorithms are converted from MatLab to dll. One of them is entropy.m. I converted it dll and using it in c#. As you know it needs MWArray to perform the calculation. I store data as segments. Fill a segment into `MWNumericArray`. Calculate the entropy of segment then clear the `MWNumericArray`. However this process is too slow. What can i do to increase the performance of the program?
Here is my code:

```
            NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));
            byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[wave.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 5];

            int read;
            int length = (int)wave.Length;
            List<MWArray> ent = new List<MWArray>();
            MWNumericArray arr1 = null;
            EntropyCalculation obj = new EntropyCalculation();
            if (file.Length % mainBuffer.Length != 0)
            {
                int value = (int)(wave.Length / mainBuffer.Length);
                length = mainBuffer.Length * value;
            }
            while (wave.Position != length)
            {
                List<double> segment = new List<double>();
                read = wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < read / 8; i++)
                {
                    segment.Add((BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * 8)));
                }
                arr1 = segment.ToArray();
                MWArray result = obj.entropy(arr1);
                ent.Add(result);
                arr1 = null;
            }
```

Comment: use `Uint16` instead of `int` , why not create an `Array[] segment` directly of length `read/8`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I changed the code as you said. However it still too slow. Probably `obj.entropy(arr1)` takes long time to calculate.

Comment: the only way to know is use of `StopWatch` and place separate debug outputs at different intervals

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try below code

```
while (wave.Position != length)
            {                
                UInt16 read = wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);
                double[] segment = new double[read / 8];
                for (UInt16 i = 0; i < segment.Length; i++)
                {
                    segment[i] =BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * 8);
                }               
                ent.Add(obj.entropy(segment));                
            }
```

Comment: `ent.Add(obj.entropy(segment));` You must use MWNumericArray as parameter instead segment. It does not calculate entropy if i use `double[]`.

Comment: You can do those operations on 2 separate lines `MWArray result = obj.entropy(segment);` and `ent.Add(result);`

Comment: .ToArray converts to double[] rite? so it should be the same type of parameter for calculating entropy ?

Comment: It does not allow directly double[]. Your logic seems correct but there is no overload method of entropy that takes double[]. First of all need to define an MWNumericArray arr1; then type arr1= segment; Thus entropy can work.